# JavaScript keyword used as function in Dojo build

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I am trying to build my project using Dojo version 1.9 with the closure compiler. In my project I am using dgrid version 1.1, and defined an extension for column filtering. When building the project, closure complains about using the JavaScript *in* keyword as function:

```
dojo.js.uncompressed.js:24719: ERROR - Parse error. missing name after . operator
                filter = filter.in(column, columnsList);
```

I also had the same issue with the *class* keyword, when defining css classes in JavaScript, but I enclosed it in quotation marks.

Is there any way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly valid JavaScript. Keywords (and other reserved words) are allowed as property names when the context is clear, as it is there.¹

You could work around CC's issue with it the same way you did in your own code, though its unpleasant to have to go re-fix it every time you upgrade Dojo:

```
filter = filter["in"](column, filtersWithEmpty);
```

---

¹ This was a change in ES5 in 2009. Specifically, in [property accessor expressions](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1), *IdentifierName* was allowed where in ES3 (there was no ES4) it had to ben an *Identifier* (where *Identifier* [is defined as](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) *IdentifierName* but not *ReservedWord*; so `class` and `in` and such don't match *Identifier*, but do match *IdentifierName*).